# Manually finish autofill context in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I've been struggling for a while getting the autofill context to "commit" in my React Native application. The current behaviour is that it does not commit at all until I force close the application. The save dialog pops up first when I close the whole application, but the desired behaviour would be for it to happen when the component is unmounted.

I've been reading about it in the [android documentations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize#ensure), and it states that normally a commit is performed when the activity finishes. By the looks of it, I'm guessing that the activities does not actually finish in React Native (even though I can see that it unmounts properly) until the whole application finishes.

I would be totally ok with this behaviour as long as there was a way for me to manually trigger such a commit. Something similar to what is mentioned in the documentation: `AutofillManager.commit()`.

1. Is there a way to actually finish an activity (React Navigation screen) in React Native? I have tried poping and reseting using React Navigation, and redirecting through React Fragments, but neither of them seems to do the trick for the autofill context to finish.
2. Is there a way to manually commit or finish the autofill context in React Native?

Comment: You can unmount a screen but a screen is not an activity in react-native. If you don't creat a new activity,the whole react-native app just have one activity.

Comment: @gwl002 Alright, that explains the current behaviour. Are you implying it is actually possible to create a new activity through React Native, or are we locked to this one activity architechture?